# I'm new to flutter and trying to use spread operator and Map into a List but I get null safety error , tried using (!) but no good

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

enter image description here

I'm new to flutter and trying to use spread operator and Map into a List but I get null safety error , tried using (!) but no good.

Comment: we can't understand with this answer.

Comment: can you please add your code to the question?

Comment: body: Center(
          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

            // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
            children: [
              Questions(questions[indexNum]['questionText']),
              ...(questions[indexNum]['answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
                return Answers(_answerOfQuestion, answer);
              }).toList()
            ],
          ),
        ),

Comment: The following _CastError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#e3bfc):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast

Comment: can you please add your complete code to the question? not in the comment

Comment: Hi @shaikhusama! Can you please add your code and all the necessary information in the body of the question? you can do that by editing your own question, this will help other user to answer your question! if you need some help in check how to write a good question please check this link! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't quite understand what you are talking about, I roughly understand where your code is wrong.

This is the example code:

> change
>
> ```
> _snapshot.data!.name
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> _snapshot.data?.name ?? "Unknown"
> ```